# Get a different value with macro every time it's used

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

I'm trying to get this to work, but so far haven't been able to think of anything.

So; what I want is a keyword that I can use in my code that would always return a different answer. This will be used for obsfucation for my program (please don't ask why).

For example:

```
#define __JUNK0  ... manual junk code here ...
#define __JUNK1  ... manual junk code here ...
#define __JUNK2  ... manual junk code here ...
#define __JUNK3  ... manual junk code here ...

#define ADD_JUNK

void main()
{
    ADD_JUNK; // adds __JUNK0
    ADD_JUNK; // now adds __JUNK1
    ADD_JUNK; // and now adds __JUNK2
    ADD_JUNK; // and finally __JUNK3
}
```

I tried to mess around with `__COUNTER__`, but then realized you can't make a "define function"...

I was also thinking about using `constexpr`, but how would I use that on a switch in compile time that basically adds an `__forceinline` function?

Is this even possible? Any ideas? <3

Comment: The preprocessor is The Devil.

Comment: This question seems slightly different than the one it's marked as duplicating.  That said, take a look at Magnus' answer in particular (third one down), but use `__COUNTER__` instead of `__LINE__` and that should do the trick for you.  If the result produced by the macro matches another defined value (e.g., `__JUNK0`, etc) it will do the proper translation.